# How to remove cookie from server side in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have an asp.net mvc 4 project where try to update my cookie, but instead of this it's create another cookie, and for example I have a 3 duplicate cookies with name "page". Anybody know how to fix this?

```
if (page != null && Request.Browser.Cookies) {
                if (Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("page")) {
                    var aCookie = new HttpCookie("page") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
                    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
                }

                var pages = new HttpCookie("page") { Value = page.ToString(), Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) };
                Response.Cookies.Add(pages);
            }
```

Comment: Remove a cookie before adding expired: Response.Cookies.Remove("page");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove your cookie from client, you should set it as expired:

```
if (page != null && Request.Browser.Cookies) {
    Response.Cookies.Remove("page");
    var aCookie = new HttpCookie("page") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
}
```

But if you only need to update it, just remove it from response and add a new version of it:

```
if (page != null && Request.Browser.Cookies) {
    Response.Cookies.Remove("page");
    var pages = new HttpCookie("page") { Value = page.ToString(), Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) };
    Response.Cookies.Add(pages);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the cookie before adding the new one.

```
if (page != null && Request.Browser.Cookies)
{
    Response.Cookies.Remove("page");
    var pages = new HttpCookie("page") { Value = page.ToString(), Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) };
    Response.Cookies.Add(pages);
}
```

Note that Response.Cookies.Remove("page") will not throw an exception if the is no page cookie, so testing for its existence is not required.